# Why is my sprite leaving copies as it moves in Monogame?

Tags: xna, 2d, sprites, monogame

I am pretty new to Monogame, and I'm trying to draw a character sprite and move it using keyboard. Instead of moving to different positions, it leaves a track of copies along the way.

I have 2 game states; one is the menu, and the other one is the level, where the sprite is called to draw.

Why is my sprite leaving copies as it moves in Monogame?

---

**Player.cs**

```
class Player : Entity
{
    private float velocity;
    private int hp;
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Rectangle hitbox;
    public Vector2 pos;
    KeyboardState oldState;

    public void Init(ContentManager content)
    {
        texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("char");
        hitbox.Width = texture.Width;
        hitbox.Height = texture.Height;
        velocity = 150f;
        pos.X = 100;
        pos.Y = 100;
    }

    public void Update(float delta)
    {
        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            pos.X += 100 * delta;
        if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            pos.X -= 100 * delta;

        oldState = newState;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        sb.Begin();
        sb.Draw(texture, pos, Color.White);
        sb.End();
    }
}
```

---

**Level1.cs**

```
class Level1 : State
{
    private Texture2D background;
    public Player player;

    public void Init(ContentManager content)
    {
        //background = content.Load<Texture2D>("Level1/bg");
        player = new Player();
        player.Init(content);
    }

    public void Update(float delta)
    {
        player.Update(delta);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb, GraphicsDeviceManager graphics)
    {
        player.Draw(sb);
    }
}
```

---

**Game1.cs**

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    State CurrentState;
    KeyboardState oldState;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    void SetState(State state)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
        CurrentState = state;
        CurrentState.Init(Content);
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        SetState(new MenuState());
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1920;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();

        var delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        CurrentState.Update(delta);

        if (CurrentState is MenuState && (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.F) 
            && oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.F)))
        {
            SetState(new Level1());
        }

        if (CurrentState is MenuState && (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape) 
            && oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Escape)))
        {
            this.Exit();
        }

        if (CurrentState is Level1 && (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape) 
            && oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Escape)))
        {
            this.Exit();
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
        oldState = newState;
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        CurrentState.Draw(spriteBatch, graphics);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing all irrelevant code (for example, you have an empty `UnloadContent` method, so it's not that), and testing/debugging extra code to try and narrow down the problem. Not sure if a value is being passed through properly? Manually set the value to a set value, and see if the problem persists. As it is, your question *may* be closed; Debugging questions are only on topic if they contain a ***minimal**, verifiable code example*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call `GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);` before rendering the state.

Comment: Thanks, it helped :) Can't figure out how i didn't notice it by myself

Comment: Yeah, you need to clear every frame or else the frames start rendering ontop of each other. Additionally, if your game is 3D, a Skybox can also replace the need for calling Clear.